# WM_SETTEXT counterpart for substring

Tags: c++, string, windows, winapi

As I take from the [documentation of `WM_SETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx), it expects a "pointer to a null-terminated string".

I wondered if there is an equivalent version of this that works on non-null-terminated strings, presumably taking a pointer (to the beginning of the string) and a number (denoting the length of the string), but I could not find anything. Did I miss something? Or is there even a deeper reason why there is no such facility?

Comment: If you're referring to something like std::string_view, winapi are far older

Comment: Well, passing around null-terminated strings is a common practice in C-sytel APIs. I don't think there is any existing equivalent of `WM_SETTEXT` that takes a pointer to buffer and size. Unless you introduce some custom message and write your own handler to process it.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152600/should-functions-of-a-c-library-always-expect-a-strings-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality because it is not necessary. If you wish to set the window text to a sub-string of a string in your program, you can simply copy that sub-string to a new string and pass that to `WM_SETTEXT`.

Remember that Win32 is a low-level API. It is already a very large API. Were it to offer the sort of convenience methods that you are looking for it would be even larger. If you wish to have such convenience, you are perfectly at liberty to wrap the Win32 functionality yourself.

There isn't any real performance implication here either. Yes it will cost you to copy the sub-string to a null-terminated buffer, but that cost is minuscule when compared with the cost of actually sending the `WM_SETTEXT` mesage and have the UI update.

Somewhat related is the functionality of multi-line edit controls. Because these contain much larger amounts of text than window captions, single-line edits, static text controls etc., they do allow you to operate on sub-strings within the control. For instance take a look at the [`EM_REPLACESEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633.aspx) message which allows you to modify a sub-string within the control, rather than be forced to replace the entire text. That is essential for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely for C style reasons. The dominant language for programming windows was C in the time that the winapi was designed and C just works with zero terminated strings.

You can achieve what you want simply with pointer operations.

```
char s[] = "hey there";

char s2[32] = {0};
strncpy(s2, s + 4, 5); // s2 will contain "there\0\0\0\0..."

SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)s2);
```